# GCR - image missing all but two files, local image is complete

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I have a container I'm deploying to Kubernetes (GKE), and the image I have built locally is good, and runs as expected, but it appears that the image being pulled from Google Container Registry, when the run command is changed to `pwd && ls` returns the output shown here:

```
I 2020-06-17T16:24:54.222382706Z /app
I 2020-06-17T16:24:54.226108583Z lost+found
I 2020-06-17T16:24:54.226143620Z package-lock.json
```

and the output of the same commands when running in the container locally, with `docker run -it <container:tag> bash` is this:

```
#${API_CONTAINER} resolves to gcr.io/<project>/container: I.E. tag gets appended

.../# docker run -it ${API_CONTAINER}latest bash   
root@362737147de4:/app# pwd
/app
root@362737147de4:/app# ls
Dockerfile       dist          files  node_modules       package.json  ssh.bat      stop_forever.bat  test      tsconfig.json
cloudbuild.yaml  environments  log    package-lock.json  src           startApi.sh  swagger.json      test.pdf  tsconfig.test.json
root@362737147de4:/app#
```

My thoughts on this start with, either the push to the registry is literally failing to work, or I'm not pulling the right one, i.e. pulling some off `latest` tag that was build by cloud build in a previous attempt to get this going.

What could be the potential issue? what could potentially fix this issue?

Edit: After using differing tags in deployment, using `--no-cache` during build, and pulling from the registry on another machine, my inclination is that GKE is having an issue pulling the image from GCR. Is there a way I can put this somewhere else, or get visibility on what's going on with the pull?

EDIT 2:

So Yes, I have a docker file I can share, but please be aware that I have inherited it, and don't understand the process that went into building this, or why some steps were necessary to the other developer. (I am definitely interested in refactoring this as much as possible.

```
FROM node:8.12.0

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install snmp -y

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm=true
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    gconf-service \
    libasound2 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libc6 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgcc1 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    ca-certificates \
    fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator1 \
    libnss3 \
    lsb-release \
    xdg-utils \
    wget

COPY . /app


# Installing puppeteer and chromium for generating PDF of the invoices.


# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg libpam-cracklib \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app/node_modules

#build the api, and move into place.... framework options are limited with the build.
RUN npm i puppeteer kiwi-server-cli && kc build -e prod
RUN rm -Rf ./environments & rm -Rf ./src && cp -R ./dist/prod/* .


# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
# USER pptruser

CMD ["google-chrome-unstable"] # I have tried adding this here as well "&&", "node", "src/server.js"
```

For pushing the image I'm using this command: 
`docker push gcr.io/<projectid>/api:latest-<version>` and I have the credentials setup with `cloud auth configure-docker` and here's a sanitized version of the yaml manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ./docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: api
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ./docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 ()
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - bash
        - -c
        - node src/server.js
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: TZ
          value: America/New_York
        image: gcr.io/<projectId>/api:latest-0.0.9
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8087
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app
          name: api-claim0
        - mountPath: /files
          name: api-claim1
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: api-claim0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: api-claim0
      - name: api-claim1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: api-claim1
status: {}
```

Comment: How do you build your image? Do you have a dockerfile to share? And how do you push your image? What's the image definition in your K8S yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution comes from the original intent of the `docker-compose.yml` file which was converted into a kubernetes manifest via a tool called `kompose`. The original docker-compose file was intended for development and as such had overrides in place to push the local development environment into the running container.

This was because of this in the yml file:

```
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - ./api/files:/files
```

which translates to this on the kubernetes manifest:

```
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /app
        name: api-claim0
      - mountPath: /files
        name: api-claim1
      volumes:
      - name: api-claim0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: api-claim0
      - name: api-claim1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: api-claim1
```

Which Kubernetes has no files to supply, and the app is essentially overwritten with an empty volume, so the file is not found.

removal of the directives in the kubernetes manifest resulted in success.

Reminder to us all to be mindful.

Answer (score 0):

To manage images [1] includes listing images in a repository, adding tags, deleting tags, copying images to a new repository, and deleting images. I hope the troubleshooting documents [2] could be helpful for you to troubleshoot the issue.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing

[2] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting